# Botão inscrever-se do youtube

Tags: html, css3, youtube

Estou fazendo uma página de listagem de vídeos do youtube e eu gostaria de fazer um botão para o usuário se inscrever no canal, mas nos exemplos que achei na internet eles vem muitas informações além do que eu preciso, no meu caso eu gostaria apenas apresentar apenas o botão "inscrever-se". Olhem o código abaixo:

```
<iframe src=http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_widget?p=CissaMagazineBR style="overflow: hidden; height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 0;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com) possui uma página para criar esse botão, basta acessar [Youtube Subscribe Button](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button?hl=pt-br).

Um exemplo de botão para se inscrever no canal do Google Developers:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

O atributo `data-channel="GoogleDevelopers"` é o [ID](http://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) ou Nome do canal.

Comment: Sim eu acessei esse site, mas o botão que ele apresenta vem escrito "youtube" ao invés de "inscrever-se"

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro você pode colocar o atributo `data-layout="full"`, assim irá mostrar o nome e imagem do seu canal. Mas acredito que a API do Youtube não disponibiliza opção para alterar o texto, senão poderiam criar um botão com outro texto "enganando" as pessoas para se inscreverem em canais.

Comment: até daria para fazer assim, mas a princípio o meu objetivo é esse http://i.imgur.com/n0Rsnzi.jpg